# How to bind ExtJS grid using Asp.net Websrvice?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, extjs

I have tried all possible ways to get the JSON data from my webservice. I can see the JSON data in fiddler. Everything is fine except the data is not binding with the grid. here is my code.

**Webservice (Mywebservice.asmx)**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://myServiceLink.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SmartlinkService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod(CacheDuration = AppConsts.NONE)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public List<SampleClass> GetTasks()
    {
        List<SampleClass> listSampleClass = new List<SampleClass>(){
                                    new SampleClass{TaskId="1",TaskName="task1"},
                                    new SampleClass{TaskId="2",TaskName="task2"},
                                    new SampleClass{TaskId="3",TaskName="task3"},
                                    new SampleClass{TaskId="4",TaskName="task4"}
                                    };
        return listSampleClass;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public string TaskId { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**User Control (UserControl.ascx)**

```
<link href="Resources/extJS/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" />
<script src="Resources/extJS/ext-all-debug.js" language="JavaScript" />
<script src="Resources/extJS/Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy.js" ResourceType="JavaScript" />
<div class="section" runat="server" id="senchaGrid">
<h1 class="mhdr">
    Project Tasks
</h1>
<div class="content">
    <div class="swrap">
        <%--sencha grid area--%>
        <div id="topic-grid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ExtJS Script Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
/**********************************Sencha Grid Code START***********************************/
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../Resources/extjs/examples/ux');
Ext.require([
'Ext.grid.*',
'Ext.data.*',
'Ext.panel.*',
'Ext.util.*',
'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
'Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin',
'Ext.ModelManager',
'Ext.layout.container.Border',
'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    // setup the state provider, all state information will be saved to a cookie
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
    Ext.namespace('EXT');

    Ext.define('myModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['TaskId', 'TaskName'],
        id: 'TaskId'
    });

    var storeData = new Ext.data.Store(
        {
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy({
                url: '/ProjectManagement/Mywebservice.asmx/GetTasks',
                actionMethods: {
                    read: 'POST'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    model: 'myModel',
                    root: 'd'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            })
        });

    //var pluginExpanded = true;

    debugger;

    var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width: 1115, height: 500,
        //title: 'Manage tasks',
        store: storeData,
        //disableSelection: true,
        //stateful: true,
        //stateId: 'stateGrid',
        loadMask: true,
        // grid columns
        columns: [
            { text: 'TaskId', dataIndex: 'TaskId', header: 'Row #'  },
            { text: 'TaskName', dataIndex: 'TaskName', header: 'Task Name'  }
            ],

        // paging bar on the bottom
        bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: storeData,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying tasks {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display"
        }),
        renderTo: 'topic-grid'
    });

    // trigger the data store load
    //store.load();
});

/**************************Sencha Grid Code END******************************/
```

**Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy.js**

```
/// <reference path="/Scripts/ext-all-debug.js" />

Ext.define('Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
require: 'Ext.data',

buildRequest: function (operation) {
    var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                            request;
    params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
    if (operation.id && !params.id) {
        params.id = operation.id;
    }

    params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);

    request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
        params: params,
        action: operation.action,
        records: operation.records,
        operation: operation,
        url: operation.url
    });
    request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
    operation.request = request;
    return request;
}
});
```

**The JSON data which I get from server (Inspected in Fiddler)**

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Mywebservice+SampleClass","TaskId":"1","TaskName":"task1"},{"__type":"Mywebservice+SampleClass","TaskId":"2","TaskName":"task2"},{"__type":"Mywebservice+SampleClass","TaskId":"3","TaskName":"task3"},{"__type":"Mywebservice+SampleClass","TaskId":"4","TaskName":"task4"}]}
```

I do not get any exception anywhere in browser. All seems perfect but still I do not understand why it is not binding the grid with data. It only shows an empty grid with column headers and paging tool bar.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your store, I see you have a proxy/reader defined - but your *model* config is on the wrong object.

*[model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-model)* should be on the store - not the reader:

```
    var storeData = new Ext.data.Store(
        {
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'myModel',
            proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy({
                url: '/ProjectManagement/Mywebservice.asmx/GetTasks',
                actionMethods: {
                    read: 'POST'
                },
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'd'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            })
        });
```